After saving changes in Summernote, it removes classes from <btn> and <a> tags
I have admin website where I am able to change text on the website without opening VSCode. I'm using Summernote for that. Editing text is fine and works like a charm. But when I'm trying to change text of a link or link of that <a> it removes all classes inside of <a>. Same problem is with buttons.
Is there any way to fix that?


<script>
    function showEditor() {
        var editorContainer = document.getElementById('editorContainer');
        var summernote = $('#summernote');
        

        // Zobrazit editor
        editorContainer.style.display = "block";

        // Načíst celý obsah z content.txt
        var content = <?php echo json_encode($content); ?>;
        
        // Inicializace editoru Summernote s celým obsahem
        summernote.summernote({
            height: 600,
            focus: true,
            callbacks: {
                onInit: function() {
                    // Manipulace s DOM, aby se zbavila třída fixed-top
                    $('#summernote').contents().find('.navbar').removeClass('fixed-top');
                },
                onImageUpload: function(files) {
                    var data = new FormData();
                    data.append('file', files[0]);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'upload.php',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: data,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function(response) {
                            var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
                            if (jsonResponse.link) {
                                summernote.summernote('insertImage', jsonResponse.link);
                            } else {
                                console.log(jsonResponse.error);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        // Nastavení načteného obsahu do editoru
        summernote.summernote('code', content);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Inicializace Summernote editoru při načtení stránky (pokud chcete)
        $('#summernote').summernote({
            height: 600,
            focus: true,
            callbacks: {
                onInit: function() {
                    // Manipulace s DOM, aby se zbavila třída fixed-top
                    $('#summernote').contents().find('.navbar').removeClass('fixed-top');
                },
                onImageUpload: function(files) {
                    var data = new FormData();
                    data.append('file', files[0]);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'upload.php',
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: data,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function(response) {
                            var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
                            if (jsonResponse.link) {
                                $('#summernote').summernote('insertImage', jsonResponse.link);
                            } else {
                                console.log(jsonResponse.error);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }); 

